# ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'b.id' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT b.id, b.bouquet, JSON_LENGTH(c.sort) - IFNULL(JSON_LENGTH(JSON_EXTRACT(c.sort, REPLACE(JSON_SEARCH(c.sort, 'all', '%m%'), '"', ''))), 0) AS total FROM bouquets b, channels c
LEFT JOIN streams st ON JSON_SEARCH(c.sort, 'one', st.id) IS NOT NULL 
LEFT JOIN streams s ON JSON_SEARCH(s.bouquet, 'one', b.id) IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY b.id ASC ORDER BY b.bouquet ASC;
```

And i get error:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'b.id' in 'on clause'
```

I try to fix this but i get out of idea...what is causing this error and how to fix it?

UPDATING QUESTION: With tables structure so it will be lot easier to track how to fix error that mysql is returning.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM bouquets;
+----+-----------+
| id | bouquet   |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Mega      |
|  2 | Resellers |
| 33 | Exchange  |
| 28 | Ex-Yu     |
|  5 | Albanian  |
+----+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM channels;
+----+--------------------------+---------+----------+
| id | sort                     | bouquet | reseller |
+----+--------------------------+---------+----------+
|  1 | ["m1","1","2","11","m2"] | ["1"]   |        1 |
| 27 | ["m1","1","2","m2"]      | ["28"]  |        1 |
| 39 | []                       | ["33"]  |        1 |
+----+--------------------------+---------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM streams;
+----+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+-------+-------+------+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+--------+
| id | channel           | stream                                                             | server     | bouquet    | notes | adult | epg  | acodec                | vcodec                                      | uptime        | bitrate | status |
+----+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+-------+-------+------+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+--------+
|  1 | CH1 1             | ["http://"] | ["1","15"] | ["1","28"] |       |     0 | 0    | mp3 ( VBR: 125 kb/s ) | h264 ( FPS: 25.0 , 720 x 576 , DAR: 16:9 )  | 1528448246933 |    1221 |      1 |
|  2 | CH1 2             | ["http://"] | ["1"]      | ["1","28"] |       |     0 | 0    | mp3 ( VBR: 125 kb/s ) | h264 ( FPS: 25.0 , 720 x 576 , DAR: 16:9 )  | 1528448259003 |    1194 |      1 |
| 11 | CH1 3             | ["http://"] | ["1","15"] | ["1"]      |       |     0 | 0    | mp3 ( VBR: 125 kb/s ) | h264 ( FPS: 25.0 , 720 x 576 , DAR: 16:9 )  | 1528448252725 |    1288 |      1 |
| 12 | CH1 4             | ["http://"] | ["15"]     | ["28"]     |       |     0 | 0    | mp2 ( VBR: 125 kb/s ) | h264 ( FPS: 50.0 , 720 x 576 , DAR: 20:11 ) | 1528448256089 |    1995 |      1 |
+----+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+------------+-------+-------+------+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Table definition?

Comment: I added table definition now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

```
SELECT b.id, b.bouquet, IFNULL(JSON_LENGTH(c.sort) - JSON_LENGTH(JSON_SEARCH(c.sort, 'all', '%m%')), 0) AS total FROM bouquets b
LEFT JOIN channels c ON JSON_SEARCH(c.bouquet, 'one', b.id) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY b.id, b.bouquet, total ORDER BY b.bouquet ASC;
```

And that gives me:

```
+----+-----------+-------+
| id | bouquet   | total |
+----+-----------+-------+
|  5 | Albanian  |     0 |
| 28 | Ex-Yu     |     2 |
| 33 | Exchange  |     0 |
|  1 | Mega      |     3 |
|  2 | Resellers |     0 |
+----+-----------+-------+
```

Thanks everybody for helping me out.

Answer (score 1):

Try define the column name in full like  `bouquets.id` and also `channels.sort` it's possible

Comment: I added as you suggested and i get: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'bouquets.id' in 'field list'

Comment: Can you check if you have a trigger in your table it might be the cause. Or maybe it's caused by a bug.

Comment: I posted second question if you have time to look at...have only one error that i im unable to solve..thanks

Answer (score 1):

make sure that column id in bouquets (b) is available. try it: b.`id` or bouquets.`id`

Comment: mysql> SELECT b.id FROM bouquets b;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  5 |
| 28 |
| 33 |
+----+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)